# Docker images not being pushed to ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, sh, amazon-ecr

I'm facing a bizarre problem. I'm pushing Docker images into ECR. 2 out of 4 images are pushed. The other 2 are left out for some reason.

My push file:

```
 if [ "$GITLAB_BRANCH" == "staging" ] || \
     [ "$GITLAB_BRANCH" == "production" ]
    then
    docker build $USERS_REPO -t $USERS:$COMMIT -f Dockerfile-$DOCKER_ENV
    docker tag $USERS:$COMMIT $REPO/$USERS:$TAG
    docker push $REPO/$USERS:$TAG         #<-- SUCCESSFULLY PUSHED

    docker build $USERS_DB_REPO -t $USERS_DB:$COMMIT -f Dockerfile
    docker tag $USERS_DB:$COMMIT $REPO/$USERS_DB:$TAG
    docker push $REPO/$USERS_DB:$TAG      #<-- SUCCESSFULLY PUSHED

    docker build $CLIENT_REPO -t $CLIENT:$COMMIT -f Dockerfile-prod --build-arg REACT_APP_USERS_SERVICE_URL=""
    echo "CLIENT 1st LINE EXECUTED"                 #  NOT EXECUTED
    docker tag $CLIENT:$COMMIT $REPO/$CLIENT:$TAG   #  NOT EXECUTED
    echo "CLIENT 2nd LINE EXECUTED"                 #  NOT EXECUTED
    docker push $REPO/$CLIENT:$TAG                  #  NOT EXECUTED

    docker build $SWAGGER_REPO -t $SWAGGER:$COMMIT -f Dockerfile-$DOCKER_ENV  #  NOT EXECUTED
    docker tag $SWAGGER:$COMMIT $REPO/$SWAGGER:$TAG                           #  NOT EXECUTED
    docker push $REPO/$SWAGGER:$TAG                                           #  NOT EXECUTED
  fi
```

Thanks to those debugging echo statements I've determined that Client and Swagger commands aren't being executed.

job log (sharing relevant output only):

```
Login Succeeded
Step 1/9 : FROM python:3.8.2-slim
---> ee07b1466448
Step 2/9 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install netcat && apt-get clean
---> Using cache
---> b0a678c8b22d
Step 3/9 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
---> Using cache
---> 25d4353ddd2c
Step 4/9 : COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt
---> 401a5620bb76
Step 5/9 : RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
---> Running in 86fac0967146
Collecting Werkzeug==0.16.1
Downloading Werkzeug-0.16.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (327 kB)
Collecting coverage==4.5.3
Downloading coverage-4.5.3.tar.gz (384 kB)
Collecting flake8===3.7.7
Downloading flake8-3.7.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (68 kB)
Collecting Flask==1.1.1
Downloading Flask-1.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (94 kB)
Collecting flask-bcrypt==0.7.1
Downloading Flask-Bcrypt-0.7.1.tar.gz (5.1 kB)
Collecting flask-cors==3.0.7
Downloading Flask_Cors-3.0.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
Collecting flask-debugtoolbar==0.10.1
Downloading Flask_DebugToolbar-0.10.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (326 kB)
Collecting flask-migrate==2.4.0
Downloading Flask_Migrate-2.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
Collecting Flask-RESTful==0.3.7
Downloading Flask_RESTful-0.3.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Collecting Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2
Downloading Flask_SQLAlchemy-2.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting Flask-Testing==0.7.1
Downloading Flask-Testing-0.7.1.tar.gz (43 kB)
Collecting gunicorn==20.0.4
Downloading gunicorn-20.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (77 kB)
Collecting psycopg2-binary==2.8.4
Downloading psycopg2_binary-2.8.4-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (3.0 MB)
Collecting pyjwt==1.7.1
Downloading PyJWT-1.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Collecting pyflakes<2.2.0,>=2.1.0
Downloading pyflakes-2.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (59 kB)
Collecting entrypoints<0.4.0,>=0.3.0
Downloading entrypoints-0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting pycodestyle<2.6.0,>=2.5.0
Downloading pycodestyle-2.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (51 kB)
Collecting mccabe<0.7.0,>=0.6.0
Downloading mccabe-0.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (8.6 kB)
Collecting click>=5.1
Downloading click-7.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (82 kB)
Collecting itsdangerous>=0.24
Downloading itsdangerous-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting Jinja2>=2.10.1
Downloading Jinja2-2.11.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (126 kB)
Collecting bcrypt
Downloading bcrypt-3.1.7-cp34-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (56 kB)
Collecting Six
Downloading six-1.14.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting Blinker
Downloading blinker-1.4.tar.gz (111 kB)
Collecting alembic>=0.7
Downloading alembic-1.4.2.tar.gz (1.1 MB)
Installing build dependencies: started
Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
Getting requirements to build wheel: started
Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
Preparing wheel metadata: started
Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'done'
Collecting aniso8601>=0.82
Downloading aniso8601-8.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (43 kB)
Collecting pytz
Downloading pytz-2019.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (509 kB)
Collecting SQLAlchemy>=0.8.0
Downloading SQLAlchemy-1.3.15.tar.gz (6.1 MB)
Installing build dependencies: started
Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
Getting requirements to build wheel: started
Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
Preparing wheel metadata: started
Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'done'
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from gunicorn==20.0.4->-r requirements.txt (line 12)) (45.2.0)
Collecting MarkupSafe>=0.23
Downloading MarkupSafe-1.1.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (32 kB)
Collecting cffi>=1.1
Downloading cffi-1.14.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (409 kB)
Collecting python-editor>=0.3
Downloading python_editor-1.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (4.9 kB)
Collecting python-dateutil
Downloading python_dateutil-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (227 kB)
Collecting Mako
Downloading Mako-1.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (75 kB)
Collecting pycparser
Downloading pycparser-2.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl (112 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: coverage, flask-bcrypt, Flask-Testing, Blinker, alembic, SQLAlchemy
Building wheel for coverage (setup.py): started
Building wheel for coverage (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Created wheel for coverage: filename=coverage-4.5.3-py3-none-any.whl size=170336 sha256=038d3ae43b6607fdfd80e1d69f79420bd823507f7be1fc20bdd16d2cdf01d518
Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/b0/4c/d7/9db997336a1ea6749f3b3b1b9edea6f6665ee86f58ae1e5b1b
Building wheel for flask-bcrypt (setup.py): started
Building wheel for flask-bcrypt (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Created wheel for flask-bcrypt: filename=Flask_Bcrypt-0.7.1-py3-none-any.whl size=5010 sha256=62300cc512e7c33a42f41ca20120672f7b6ff54c5009a208c32b3fc50bf4da62
Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/8a/d9/0e/dc762c4ebc76f581397a2e25991db6efd148640b5616ab9210
Building wheel for Flask-Testing (setup.py): started
Building wheel for Flask-Testing (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Created wheel for Flask-Testing: filename=Flask_Testing-0.7.1-py3-none-any.whl size=8167 sha256=972152da9797e69bc3682dd259120d95076afdf31e1f3f6dca9e68cb745b84f8
Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/1e/61/04/028fc73af661e18862396627606c5898a5da45f13ac0e37711
Building wheel for Blinker (setup.py): started
Building wheel for Blinker (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Created wheel for Blinker: filename=blinker-1.4-py3-none-any.whl size=13452 sha256=bba96e4a53181a424212eaa71d27e74fa0d13c3914867e58b0484a0a60ecd377
Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/b7/a5/68/fe632054a5eadd531c7a49d740c50eb6adfbeca822b4eab8d4
Building wheel for alembic (PEP 517): started
Building wheel for alembic (PEP 517): finished with status 'done'
Created wheel for alembic: filename=alembic-1.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl size=159543 sha256=298ba2526878708a54b8db0ad2ab5ef05be4438963dd09bec1a50b59c8a15508
Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/70/08/70/cea787a7e95817b831469fa42af076046e55a05f7c94657463
Building wheel for SQLAlchemy (PEP 517): started
Building wheel for SQLAlchemy (PEP 517): finished with status 'done'
Created wheel for SQLAlchemy: filename=SQLAlchemy-1.3.15-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl size=1183124 sha256=50418d7071fd37b2db91f19a375389422fdc56895072af53df4a6665537d893b
Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/d1/0c/78/33448c81fd8e458d60897744f30462ca39e682637ec9591c0d
Successfully built coverage flask-bcrypt Flask-Testing Blinker alembic SQLAlchemy
Installing collected packages: Werkzeug, coverage, pyflakes, entrypoints, pycodestyle, mccabe, flake8, click, itsdangerous, MarkupSafe, Jinja2, Flask, pycparser, cffi, Six, bcrypt, flask-bcrypt, flask-cors, Blinker, flask-debugtoolbar, SQLAlchemy, python-editor, python-dateutil, Mako, alembic, Flask-SQLAlchemy, flask-migrate, aniso8601, pytz, Flask-RESTful, Flask-Testing, gunicorn, psycopg2-binary, pyjwt
Successfully installed Blinker-1.4 Flask-1.1.1 Flask-RESTful-0.3.7 Flask-SQLAlchemy-2.3.2 Flask-Testing-0.7.1 Jinja2-2.11.1 Mako-1.1.2 MarkupSafe-1.1.1 SQLAlchemy-1.3.15 Six-1.14.0 Werkzeug-0.16.1 alembic-1.4.2 aniso8601-8.0.0 bcrypt-3.1.7 cffi-1.14.0 click-7.1.1 coverage-4.5.3 entrypoints-0.3 flake8-3.7.7 flask-bcrypt-0.7.1 flask-cors-3.0.7 flask-debugtoolbar-0.10.1 flask-migrate-2.4.0 gunicorn-20.0.4 itsdangerous-1.1.0 mccabe-0.6.1 psycopg2-binary-2.8.4 pycodestyle-2.5.0 pycparser-2.20 pyflakes-2.1.1 pyjwt-1.7.1 python-dateutil-2.8.1 python-editor-1.0.4 pytz-2019.3
Removing intermediate container 86fac0967146
---> 24e9fd372978
Step 6/9 : COPY ./entrypoint.sh /usr/src/app/entrypoint-prod.sh
---> a8a8ff286b9a
Step 7/9 : RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/entrypoint-prod.sh
---> Running in 3e5271e99947
Removing intermediate container 3e5271e99947
---> ed979b6a92d2
Step 8/9 : COPY . /usr/src/app
---> 98ae33e1a57f
Step 9/9 : CMD ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint-prod.sh"]
---> Running in 47ec0411fa6f
Removing intermediate container 47ec0411fa6f
---> aa4f69380842
Successfully built aa4f69380842
Successfully tagged test-driven-users:7cd9fc49
The push refers to repository [274725968600.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/test-driven-users]
84b82b2ee3ff: Preparing
863cf2890ceb: Preparing
863cf2890ceb: Preparing
71378740a723: Preparing
116445b56805: Preparing
3e98b52f064e: Preparing
241d1d8b8b7e: Preparing
fe108eef54ea: Preparing
df4dc71f749c: Preparing
64b4e3ecc0d6: Preparing
bdc3a0723efa: Preparing
f2cb0ecef392: Preparing
241d1d8b8b7e: Waiting
fe108eef54ea: Waiting
df4dc71f749c: Waiting
64b4e3ecc0d6: Waiting
bdc3a0723efa: Waiting
f2cb0ecef392: Waiting
116445b56805: Pushed
863cf2890ceb: Pushed
84b82b2ee3ff: Pushed
3e98b52f064e: Pushed
df4dc71f749c: Layer already exists
64b4e3ecc0d6: Layer already exists
fe108eef54ea: Layer already exists
bdc3a0723efa: Layer already exists
f2cb0ecef392: Layer already exists
71378740a723: Pushed
241d1d8b8b7e: Pushed
production: digest: sha256:f14a77a6e8555ecb29c5d7cd1b1435f2835e43c483ae530ec7e877974bc6b32a size: 2830
Users pushed
Step 1/2 : FROM postgres:12.2-alpine
---> 155381193772
Step 2/2 : ADD create.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
---> 21a0338e2cd6
Successfully built 21a0338e2cd6
Successfully tagged test-driven-users_db:7cd9fc49
The push refers to repository [274725968600.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/test-driven-users_db]
0d9977ee4514: Preparing
2552a4140be9: Preparing
4a517dd4afb0: Preparing
08185ac708af: Preparing
8c2dd7a8ecdf: Preparing
230e876ebf83: Preparing
fe9df245e483: Preparing
e384dedb3f12: Preparing
5216338b40a7: Preparing
230e876ebf83: Waiting
fe9df245e483: Waiting
e384dedb3f12: Waiting
5216338b40a7: Waiting
2552a4140be9: Layer already exists
4a517dd4afb0: Layer already exists
08185ac708af: Layer already exists
8c2dd7a8ecdf: Layer already exists
230e876ebf83: Layer already exists
fe9df245e483: Layer already exists
e384dedb3f12: Layer already exists
5216338b40a7: Layer already exists
0d9977ee4514: Pushed
production: digest: sha256:8ff80fd2a71f71524ea3c293094099c6d110ad60c5118654bd899a1ef78f8b8f size: 2192
Database pushed
Step 1/20 : FROM node:11.12.0-alpine as builder
---> 09084e4ff58d
Step 2/20 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
---> Using cache
---> 2a5d0819135f
Step 3/20 : RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .gyp python make g++
---> Using cache
---> 56864a4e5367
Step 4/20 : ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
---> Using cache
---> 0e0bf35b6ecc
Step 5/20 : COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
---> 8616da17869a
Step 6/20 : COPY package-lock.json /usr/src/app/package-lock.json
---> 7d43a249c366
Step 7/20 : RUN npm install --no-optional
---> Running in 11527112e824
> cypress@4.1.0 postinstall /usr/src/app/node_modules/cypress
> node index.js --exec install
Installing Cypress (version: 4.1.0)
[11:00:49] Downloading Cypress [started]
[11:00:49] Downloading Cypress 0% 0s [title changed]
…
…

[11:00:51] Downloading Cypress 83% 0s [title changed]
[11:00:51] Downloading Cypress 98% 0s [title changed]
[11:00:52] Downloaded Cypress [title changed]
[11:00:52] Downloaded Cypress [completed]
[11:00:52] Unzipping Cypress [started]
[11:00:53] Unzipping Cypress 0% 0s [title changed]
[11:00:54] Unzipping Cypress 1% 161s [title changed]
[11:00:54] Unzipping Cypress 1% 162s [title changed]
[11:00:54] Unzipping Cypress 1% 163s [title changed]
[11:00:55] Unzipping Cypress 1% 334s [title changed]
[11:00:55] Unzipping Cypress 1% 335s [title changed]
…
…

[11:01:06] Unzipping Cypress 9% 140s [title changed]
[11:01:08] Unzipping Cypress 9% 164s [title changed]
[11:01:08] Unzipping Cypress 100% 0s [title changed]
[11:01:08] Unzipped Cypress [title changed]
[11:01:08] Unzipped Cypress [completed]
[11:01:08] Finishing Installation [started]
[11:01:08] Finished Installation /root/.cache/Cypress/4.1.0 [title changed]
[11:01:08] Finished Installation /root/.cache/Cypress/4.1.0 [completed]
You can now open Cypress by running: node_modules/.bin/cypress open
https://on.cypress.io/installing-cypress
added 2034 packages from 768 contributors and audited 38602 packages in 76.256s
found 1073 vulnerabilities (1058 low, 14 moderate, 1 high)
run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
Saving cache 
00:02 
Uploading artifacts for successful job 
00:02 
Job succeeded
```

As you can see it exits out with "Job succeeded" with no errors indicating why it couldn't run the other 2 docker images.

Any suggestions ?

**Update:**

including `set -euo pipefail` revealed:  `line 4: GITLAB_PULL_REQUEST: unbound variable`

relevant code:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -euo pipefail

if [ -z "$GITLAB_PULL_REQUEST" ] || [ "$GITLAB_PULL_REQUEST" == "false" ]  # <-- LINE 4
then
  if [[ "$GITLAB_BRANCH" == "staging" ]]; then
    export DOCKER_ENV=stage
  elif [[ "$GITLAB_BRANCH" == "production" ]]; then
    export DOCKER_ENV=prod
  fi

  if [ "$GITLAB_BRANCH" == "staging" ] || \
     [ "$GITLAB_BRANCH" == "production" ]
  then
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: Are you able to build those two images locally?

Comment: Yes, they work just fine locally.

Comment: So, what have been changed in the environment that you can't build that? Last step it's doing is: `Step 7/20 : RUN npm install --no-optional`. Take a look on that and be aware if you machine has internet connection.

Comment: Which CI are you using? I think this is most likely an issue with the CI job timeout. You can confirm this by changing the order of the docker builds.

Comment: I'm using GitLab CI runner. I'm gonna swap the order and report back. I believe the job timeout on the GitLab runner is 1 hour.

Comment: So I swapped the order. Client and Swagger first and then the other 2 and guess what. None of them were pushed ! This problem is more bizarre than I thought.

Comment: I can see from the job log that whatever it is that is going wrong with the build it's happening right after Cypress finishes installation. But locally the image builds just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You're assuming that the shell script will stop if one of the steps fails. Sadly, shell scripts don't do that: they'll happily keep running even if a command fails.

So it may be that one of the build stages is failing.

For bash, you can do `set -euo pipefail` to get slightly more reasonable behavior. See http://redsymbol.net/articles/unofficial-bash-strict-mode/ for details.

Comment: Well ... my assumption is backed by the fact that the other images weren't pushed into ECR when I moved Client image to top. When I moved the image build command to the bottom all 3 images were pushed. So there must be something fishy going on with the Client image while being built in GitLab runner.

Comment: Is "unbound variable" just another way of saying "undefined" ?

Comment: Yeah, mean it's not set to anything.

Comment: So I fixed the undefined variable. But now it doesn't give me any error but the Client image still not being pushed. Now it's the time when knowing bunch of debugging techniques really come in handy.